# Going back to the old state of a branch in Git after pulling

Tags: git

I pulled a repo to my master branch. I copied master into another branch, newBranch in which i had made important changes. How can i go back to the original newBranch before the pull.  I tried 'git revert 3dfd659' after resolving all the conflicts, but i still have this error message.

error: could not revert 3dfd659... changes
hint: after resolving the conflicts, mark the corrected paths
hint: with 'git add ' or 'git rm '
hint: and commit the result with 'git commit'

I still can't get it right after adding and commiting the changes as the error message indicates.

Please help.

Comment: Try `git merge --abort`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't clearly get your problem. However, here's what I have to say:

1. At any time, if you want to go back to a state of a commit you, you can use either reset or revert. First of all, you have to have a commit hash, which you can get from the log `git log --all --oneline`. The `all` to print all log from all branches. The `oneline` to print only the subject and the hash condensed. Now, that you have the hash, you can use it with reset or revert. revert creates a new commit with undoing the changes introduced. reset really goes back to the commit you specified. reset with --hard is a dangerous command as it modifies the history, the index and the working directory. The syntax for reset is `git reset --hard <commit>`. You can also specify files to change only `git reset --hard -- <file>...`.
2. After resolving conflicts, you have to add the files again to mark them as resolved `git add <file>`.

Comment: Great! It would be nice if you mark the question as solved by my answer.